# What is the difficulty/advantage to obfuscate a multi-thread program?

Tags: multithreading, obfuscation, deobfuscation

According to my knowledge, several obfuscation strategies are widely used(or at least described in academic) like:

- complicating control flow

  1. inserting bogus control-flow
  2. control-flow flattening
  3. jump through branch functions
  4. opaque values from array aliasing
- Opaque Predicates

  1. opaque predicates from pointer aliasing
- dynamic obfuscation

  1. self-modifying state machine
  2. code as key material

From the examples they give when introducing these obfuscation ways, multi-thread program has not been talked.

So I am wondering whether these strategies are feasible(or even feasible, but not very practical) in multi-thread programs?

Answer (score 0):

Why would they not be applicable?

Obfuscation basically tries to make analysis hard.   I'd imagine you could add a few more techniques based on multithreading, to leverage its already difficult to understand nature:

```
*  obfuscated synchronization, esp. conditional or multiple waits
*  bogus fork/joins
*  things that look like data races
```

In terms of difficulty: obfuscation is relatively easy once you know what you want to do, and you have good machinery to manipulate source code.  (The latter is the hard part, not the former).